# Making a Jpanel Scrollable

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm having some problems with my code...

I made it and everything works... but my content goes out of bounds quickly so I needed to make it scrollable.. This is when everything went to hell...

My code=

```
public Main() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 1200);


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(contentPane);
    Dimension d = new Dimension(1000,800);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(d);
    frame.add(scroll);
    Arrays.sort(genres);
    System.out.println("test1");
    createGui();

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Any help is very much appreciated :/ I tried tons of solutions but either the scrollbars don't show up or nothing shows..

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

Don't use a null layout.

Layout managers have many functions. One is to set the size/location of components added to the panel. The other is do determine the preferred size of the panel. The scrollbars will appear automatically when the preferred size of the panel is greater than the size of the scrollpane. When you use a null layout the preferred size is (0, 0) so there is no reason to show the scrollbars.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples using layout managers.

If you are doing custom painting on your panel, then you would override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom panel to make the scrollbars work properly.

Comment: Dimension d = new Dimension(1000,800);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(d); I'm using this code to fix the preferredSize() and there isn't any painting on my panel

Comment: And changing the layout doesn't fix anything, with this code, I'm not seeing anything.. :/

Comment: @EwardSomers, Of course you don't see anything. You haven't added any components to the panel so the preferred size of the panel is less than the size of the scrollpane so there is no reason for the scrollbars to appear.

Comment: This is obviously only part of the code, but earlier on I added tons of components. I added a print to check if it works. All the items are added but aren't being displayed.

Comment: @EwardSomers The components did not display because you used a null layout. Create your GUI properly using layout managers and you won't have this problem. If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.